# How to use a remote python interpreter in remote development - ssh in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Microsoft recently released remote development support for SSH.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh

However, in python, if you click "select python interpreter". The interpreter available to be chosen is only for a set of python interpreters in anaconda.

The interpreter available to be chosen are in:

```
~/anaconda3/*
/usr/bin/python
```

I have a custom python interpreter in a custom location. My interpreter is in `~/projects/myproject/bin/python`

How do we configure a remote python interpreter by giving it a path?

Note: I have configured `setting.json`

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/python",
```

But it does not seem to respect it

Comment: Add "python": "path/to/python" in launch.json

Answer (score 1):

managed to make it work with

1. update vscode
2. my files:

```
# settings.json
{
  "python.pythonPath": "/custom/bin/python"
}
```

```
# launch.json
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}"
  },
...
```

3. restarted vscode
4. F1 -> select Interpreter

Comment: For me, using the Microsoft "Remote - SSH" package, I just needed to switch the python interpreter from the server default by doing F1 -> Python: Select Interpreter